# Use HttpSessionState to store Token/Claims

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, wif, claims-based-identity, thinktecture-ident-model

Is there a solution available to use HttpSessionState to store the Token ?

I know we can enable session to make the authentication cookie smaller :

```
FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.IsSessionMode = true;
```

From what I understood, with the default implementation, the token is stored in memory. http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2010/05/26/YOUR-FEDAUTH-COOKIES-ON-A-DIET-ISSESSIONMODE-TRUE/

The HttpSession is not used even if a custom provider is set.

Thinktecture IdentityModel allows us to use a custom token repository by [implementing `ITokenCacheRepository`](http://brockallen.com/2013/02/21/server-side-session-token-caching-in-wif-and-thinktecture-identitymodel/) but it requires an external storage, using the session might be bad (expiration, scope...).

Why the default TokenCache uses an in memory solution instead of Host Session provider ? Is there an easy and safe way to use host's session state ?

Answer (score 0):

While I didn't tried to store the Token in Session, I implemented `ITokenCacheRepository` from Thinktecture.IdentityModel using a Redis cache.

The code is available here : https://github.com/guillaume-fr/RedisTokenCache

That may help anybody looking for a way to store Tokens on server side in a Cloud / WebFarm environment. I won't accept my answer as it doesn't says how we could use Session or why we couldn't.

Comment: Looking for implementing an ITokenCacheRepository based on httpSession I found this post. Any insight of what is wrong about this approach?

Comment: I don't really remember but here is what comes to mind : check where is stored your httpSession (if memory, it will fail in cloud/web farm) it must be secure and work cross instance, ensure that httpSession is already available at the time you need the token in the pipeline.